# Flask http://0.0.0.0:5000/ not reachable

Tags: python, flask, chatbot

Whenever I am running flask python main file, I am getting this ""**Running on [http://0.0.0.0:5000/**"](http://0.0.0.0:5000/**%22). When I tap the url I am getting "this site can't be reached". Can anyone explain and solve this issue please?

Comment: Have you tried copying the url or typing `http://localhost:5000` in a browser?

Comment: When you "tap" the url? Are you trying to access the app/server from a mobile device?

Answer (score 3):

The URL that it is displaying is not reachable because 0.0.0.0 is just a placeholder. You need to figure out which address it is actually listening on. If you are trying to reach a server from the same machine, try http://localhost:5000/; if you are accessing it over the network, you need to figure out what addresses the server is actually reachable by.

It's not always obvious from within the server itself, though the output of `ifconfig` or similar probably works at least within the same local network. Try https://whatismyip.com/ or a similar service from within the server if you need to see its publicly routable address (assuming still that there is no firewall or etc in place which is blocking this port from public access).

Answer (score -1):

Please try adding host parameter:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='localhost') #Or change to your ip, such as '192.168.30.56'
```

Console out put:

```
Running on http://localhost:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```